# C# - Exception handling in frameworks

Tags: c#, exception, frameworks, namespaces

I have to write a FTP (AUTH TSL) framework in C#. I'm a noob at writing frameworks.
E.g. when I prove that a file exists and it doesn't, what should I do?

- Throwing a Exception for the programmer that uses the framwork?
- Printing a ExceptionMessage (Console.WriteLine()) without throwing a
  Exception?

What is professional in this case?

Comment: If you were using this framework, what would you want to have happen?

Comment: The exception to being professional, is swallowing exceptions...

Comment: As stated above, what would you like to happen, or rather, what would you expect to happen. For example, when you call a method CheckFileExists, that returns a boolean, one would expect a true or false. However, if the connection fails, I'd expect an exception, because it could not be determined if the file exists. However if the same method would return a result such as an enumeration, with one of the options being for example 'CouldNotDetermine', I could write my own logic depending on the outcome. Finally, there's always an option to include a parameter 'Throw' which, well, throws if needed

Comment: OK, the user have to set the Username, Password and the Host. When he tries to upload/download a file I must check this data. What should I do? Throwing a custom Exception or what?

Comment: In C# you usually only throw exceptions, if something really "unexpected" happens. Not being able to open a connection because the password is missing is not unexpected. So your function should return a value that indicates whether the action was successfull or not. Ripping out the network cable while data is downloaded is _more_ unexpected, but could still be just a normal failure one would expect the framework to handle. If your framework is passed a file with size -6MB, the destination folder is null, or the operating system tells you it ran out of RAM, that is worth an expception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Broad question actually, but there are some clues to get you on the way:

1. Never use `Console.WriteLine()` or any stuff like that in a framework.
2. For methods like `Framework.FileExists`, if file doesn't exist, simply return `false` value. That's the true nature of the Boolean return value. That's more semantic.
3. For operations that encounter problems, throw a custom, or predefined exception. For example, if you need an argument and you want to get sure that no null has been passed to your method, then simply check the argument in your method's body and if it's null, throw `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Also, document any exceptions that can be thrown by the method. A consumer of the framework needs to know what can go wrong in order to use the framework correctly.

Answer (score 1):

To pass an "error code" back as return value, it is common to use enums.
Your upload method could return

```
public enum UploadResult
{
    Success,
    PasswordInvalid,
    UserInvalid,
    FileNotFound,
    HostNotFound
}
```

The user of your framework then can easily use it like this:

```
if (Ftp.Upload(User, Pass, Host, File) != UploadResult.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sorry, something went terribly wrong.");
}
```

or check for more specific reasons and try again.

Edit: And as written in my comment to your original posting: If something *really* unexpected happens or the user input is clearly invalid, throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would throw an Exception, because then it's clear to the user of the framework what happend. But i would wirte my own exception-classes.

I won't work with return-codes, because then the user have to know them and interpret them. There can be made errors.